# typeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types >>>

Tags: python

```
>>> names=['jill','jack']
>>> isinstance(names,list)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#291>", line 1, in <module>
    isinstance(names,list)
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types
>>>
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: `isinstance(names, __builtins__.list)` will work!! And "DON'T" use such keywords which are reserved by python! Also can you add what `globals()['list']` returns??

Comment: thank you guys!! Am trying examples given in headfirst python. Anyways   thanks you for your prompt reply.

Comment: globals()['list']  ('rango', 26, 'murphy', 22)..

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You've stomped on `list` by assigning to a local variable of the same name. Don't do that.

Comment: It pains me so much that this is even possible.
Just makes me long for a language with strong typing, or maybe just a `const`.

Comment: Not a great solution since you've identified the cause of the problem but not how to fix it.

Answer (score 21):

Apply this one :

```
if isinstance(names, type([])):
```

Comment: rather `if isinstance(names, type([])):`

Comment: type(list) returns the metatype `type`. Why would you want to use that?

Answer (score 8):

But this works in Python (v3.7.1:260ec2c36a, Oct 20 2018, 14:05:16) [MSC v.1915 32 bit (Intel)] on win32：

```
>>> names=['jill', 'jack']
>>> isinstance(names, list)
True
```

Answer (score 6):

This can also happen if you've accidentally messed up the foreign key field syntax in your model. When writing a foreign key field, you can have:

```
ModelName
```

or:

```
'app_name.ModelName'
```

but you cannot have:

```
'ModelName'
```

Learnt that one the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

This situation happens when you refer to model which is not actual existed and you are referencing it in a fk relation with 'app_name.model_name' syntax.

The excerpt is, in lieu of `app_name.model_name` in fk, first remove all those field with the syntax mentioned and apply migrations.

==> like the one below:

```
company = models.ForeignKey('core_company.Company', 
null=True, 
blank=True, 
verbose_name="Company", 
on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related",
related_query_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)ss")
```

***** ***SOLUTION*** *****

Remove this field from the model and first make sure that `core_company.Company` model actually exists. if it doesn't first create migration for Company model and apply that migration. After that you can refer it like above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jupyter notebook, then do this:

`del str`