# Pandas: Select rows whose dictionary contains a specific value

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe, in which one column contain a dictionaries for every row. I want to select rows whose dictionary contains a specific value. Doesn't matter which key contains it.

The dictionaries have many levels (they contain a lot of lists, with a lot of dictionaries, again with a lot of lists and so on).
The data could look similar to this, but with the dictionaries being more complex:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [{"a":1}, {"b":**specific_value**}, {"c":3}]})
   A         B
0  1  {'a': 1}
1  2  {'b': 2}
2  3  {'c': 3}
```

I tried:

```
df.B.apply(lambda x : 'specific_value' in x.values())
```

To which I get "false" even the rows that I know contain the 'specific_value'. I am unsure if it is because of the layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a recursive function to search for the *specific value*:

```
import pandas as pd


def nested_find_value(d, needle=4):
    # we assume d is always a list or dictionary
    haystack = d.values() if isinstance(d, dict) else d
    
    for hay in haystack:
        if isinstance(hay, (list, dict)):
            yield from nested_find_value(hay, needle)
        else:
            yield hay == needle


def find(d, needle=4):
    return any(nested_find_value(d, needle))


df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [{"a": 1}, {"b": {"d": 4}}, {"c": 3}]})

result = df["B"].apply(find)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: B, dtype: bool
```

In the example above the *specific value* is `4`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code you wrote doesn't seem to working on my python version though. I get "TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types".

I'm thinking it has something to do with this, but I don't understand the answers they provide:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681096/typeerror-isinstance-arg-2-must-be-a-type-or-tuple-of-types

Comment: @EmilJessen Are any of your variables named dict or list?

Comment: No.

I did however, realise that using "if isinstance(hay, (__builtins__.list, __builtins__.dict)):" works.